# Is there any way that we can check mouse right click cut event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
eventTarget.addEventListener("keyup", event) {
if (event.keyCode === 46 || event.keyCode === 8) {
//46 and are keyboard 'delete' and 'backspace' button value
// If we pressed delete button in description text area then Disable Save Button
} 
});
```

Similar way, I want for mouse right click cut event.
If I selected cut option from mouse right click in description text area then disable the Save button.

If anyone know how to do for mouse cut event then please help me.

Waiting for your reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to test for the actions that lead up to an event being triggered. Just create [a `cut` event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/cut_event).

Comment: Or use [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) to detect any kind of change to a form control element on realtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to test for the actions that lead up to an event being triggered. Just create [a `cut` event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/cut_event).

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
document.querySelector("textarea").addEventListener("cut", function(event){
  btn.disabled = true;
});
```

```html
<textarea>Cut some text here</textarea>
<button>Save</button>
```